# GitHub . How to revert a single file from PR from GitHub website itself

Tags: github

**Question**:  Github. How to revert a single file from PR from the GitHub website itself

**Context**:  In one of my PRs, I want to revert a file `go.sum` to the state before my commits in the PR .

[image]

Now I was wondering whether there was an option to do this directly from the GitHub website (similar to the delete file we have already).

I am aware we can do this by making changes locally in git and pushing it to my fork I am looking for if there is a way to do this directly from the webpage without manually editing.

Comment: Would you be able to use GitHub Codespaces for this?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy  I prefer not to if there is a more easier way